# Sending Keys to an Application with Win32Api

Tags: python, winapi, roblox, pywin32

I am trying to send keys to an application so I can have my player move around while I am gone. I took a look at the win32api and it's what I need, but for some reason, when I run my code, it does nothing, however, when I try to send keys to another application like Notepad, it works normally.

My code

```
hwndMain = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Roblox")
hwndChild = win32gui.GetWindow(hwndMain, win32con.GW_CHILD)

while True:
    win32api.PostMessage(hwndChild, win32con.WM_CHAR, 0x44, 0)
    sleep(1)
```

Doesn't work, but when I do this it works

```
hwndMain = win32gui.FindWindow("Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad")
hwndChild = win32gui.GetWindow(hwndMain, win32con.GW_CHILD)

while True:
    win32api.PostMessage(hwndChild, win32con.WM_CHAR, 0x44, 0)
    sleep(1)
```

These are the window names and hwnds
`0x7101aa Roblox`